# How do I make a website with an interactive table that fetches data from an SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite

Here's an example of a table full of cool data:

http://databases.sun-sentinel.com/Orlando/ftlaudosuniversities/ftlauduniversities_list.php

It looks like it gets its table from an SQL database.

I was wondering if there are any tutorials on how to do this, or if anyone here knows how.

Comment: http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitephptutorial/ might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Hm, looks like it's time for me to learn PHP too.